# How can I resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver when using Spring 3.1 with Hibernate 4.0.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I recently upgraded to Hibernate 4.0.1.Final and am receiving the following error on context startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2823)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1655)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:71)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
```

My configuration is as follows:

```xml
<!-- Holding Properties for hibernate -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>

    <!-- Configure annotated beans -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />

    <!-- Drives transactions using local JPA APIs -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <!-- Creates a EntityManagerFactory for use with the Hibernate JPA provider -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
        p:packagesToScan="com.mypackage.entity"
        p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter"/>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                p:showSql="true"
                p:generateDdl="false"
                p:database="MYSQL"
                p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />

    <!-- Deploys datasource-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:${mysql.port}/?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
        p:username="bla"
        p:password="bla123"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Some of the dependencies are:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>                    
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>                  
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
```

And spring version of: 3.1.0.RELEASE

I am assuming that something is trying to read an xml file.  There are no hibernate xml configurations for hibernate other than the properties file. Persistence.xml does not exist in current setup.  Why or who is seeking a class that does not exist in hibernate 4.0.1?

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError specifically means that a class that was available at compile time is not on the classpath at runtime. Are you certain that you've completely updated your dependencies?

Comment: I don't use `hibernate-annotations` but it seems odd to mix version `3.5.6` of the annotations and `4.0.1` of core. Have you ensured that this is correct?

Comment: I would say yes, but apparently I am wrong, so how can i verify?  I am seeking the location of this file and it seems to have been omitted from hibernate 4+.  A google search on this class shows it only existing in versions bellow Hibernate 4

Comment: @beerbajay if i omit hibernate-annotations dependency then my compiler complains... looks like hibernate has not updated this component to same version to the rest of the components.

Comment: That indicates to me that they have replaced it in some way, perhaps by including the annotations in core, or that they have not yet released an updated `hibernate-annotations` package, though this seems a bit odd.

Comment: The dopcumentation says: *Download and unpack the Hibernate Core distribution from the Hibernate website. Hibernate 3.5 and onward contains Hibernate Annotations.* hibernate-annotations is embedded into hibernate-core now. You must not use hibernate-annotations. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#setup-requirements

Comment: @yock I just checked the output maven target directory for my war which includes the data jar with these settings and dependencies.  Sure enough all the appropriate Hibernate jars specified in maven are present.

Comment: The annotations are in `hibernate-core` since 4.0. You should not mix versions. And there should be no need for so much manual exclusions if you use libraries that are pretty much standard like Hibernate and Spring.

Comment: As recommended I removed Hibernate-annotations dependency and removed the offending compile errors that resulted from using `org.hibernate.annotations.ForceDiscriminator` which doesn't exist anymore. The resulting project build works and starts up as expected.  Now to verify my discriminators work properly :)

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Can someone post the the answer to this?  i don't seem to have the privilege to do so. The answere: The root cause seems to have been a mix and match of hibernate-annotation versions.  It is not recommended to include a separate dependency for Hibernate-annotations when using hibernate-core 3.5+ for it is already included within.  Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Per the [Hibernate annotations 3.5 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#setup-requirements):*

> Hibernate 3.5 and onward contains Hibernate Annotations.

You should remove the dependency on `hibernate-annotations`, and remove the `exclude`s from the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency. Generally, you should not mix versions of dependent packages.

* and JB Nizet's comment.

Comment: WOW, first time I fix the dependency by *removing* something, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>tck-utils-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem now it's fine with my these dependencies.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- If using JPA (2), add: -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue, after removing dependencies for hibernate annotation, I was able to run my code successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the case for this issue, but I had a similar dependency error on 'hibernate envers', after I removed it the program started working.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>`
```